# TurboJs: Support for lockfiles without a 'packages' field isn't implemented yet

Tags: javascript, node.js, package.json, monorepo, turbo

After upgrading turbo from `1.8.2` to `1.8.3`, I receive this error message:

```
Issues occurred when constructing package graph. Turbo will function, but some features may not be available:  18 errors occurred:
        * Support for lockfiles without a 'packages' field isn't implemented yet
        * No lockfile available to do analysis on
        * No lockfile available to do analysis on
...
```

Everything was working fine until now. I googled this error and found **no results**. So I write this question for future reference.

Comment: Any workaround which might have worked for you? In a similar situation can not find anything on the web

Comment: Sorry, I can't remember how I managed to solve this problem. Have you tried to delete all node_modules in all project folders and retry `npm i` from root ?